# sails.js access model method from all controllers

Tags: sails.js

I have a dynamic header menu, populated by a model method call. Instead of calling the model from every single controller, where can I put this? I tried services and I don't think models are available at that point. Policies does not seem like the best place, but if that is the only option i'll use it.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: Someone asked that question already. You can create policy that will be added to all controllers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212856/sails-js-send-data-from-partial-controller-to-partial-view?rq=1

Comment: That may work, but definitely not the option I was looking for. Sails.js is not the MVC solution I was looking for. Great for simple CRUD applications , but not so great for robust applications. Thank you for your reply @Bonanza